# Unable to get data from db to print on browser using servlet

Tags: postgresql, servlets, jdbc

This is my code I write to display results of a query from db to the browser using servlet,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet{

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // JDBC driver name and database URL
     // static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
      final String DB_URL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";

      //  Database credentials
      final String USER = "postgres";
      final String PASS = "postgres";

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Database Result";
      String docType =
        "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
         "transitional//en\">\n";
         out.println(docType +
         "<html>\n" +
         "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
         "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
         "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n");
      try{
         // Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

         // Open a connection
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

         // Execute SQL query
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql;
         sql = "SELECT docid,term,term_frequency,tf FROM fea2";
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         out.println("<h4>connected to db</h4>");

         // Extract data from result set
         while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            int docid  = rs.getInt("docid");
            int term_frequency = rs.getInt("term_frequency");
            String term = rs.getString("term");
            float tf = rs.getFloat("tf");

            //Display values
            out.println("ID: " + docid + "<br>");
            out.println(", Age: " + term_frequency + "<br>");
            out.println(", First: " + term + "<br>");
            out.println(", Last: " + tf + "<br>");
         }
         out.println("</body></html>");
         out.println("got data from db");
         // Clean-up environment
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

This code only prints as "Database Result" on browser but not the contents from the table fea1. This table is present and populated with data.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DatabaseAccess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DatabaseAccess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DatabaseAccess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DatabaseAccess</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I do not know what else is wrong. I want the result of my query to be printed on browser.Please help.  Any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? what is the expected bahaviour and what you got?

Comment: how far does the code get in the servlet?  try adding print statements to narrow down how far you are getting.  What stack trace are you getting?  You are printing the the stack trace to System.out, so do you know how to find it?  If you're not sure, `e.printStackTrace(out)` instead to print the stack to the servlet response.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to write an answer that will solve your question as it is currently written.

Here are my suggestions:

- add more print statements to help you narrow in on which line of code isn't working
- instead of printing your stack traces using `e.printStackTrace()` (which prints to System.out), print the stack traces right to your servlet output using `e.printStackTrace(out)`

Finding out how far you are getting in the servlet is key to solving the problem.

It's probably one of these issues:

- `Class.forName()` is failing because the postgresql driver isn't on your classpath (or not visible to the Servlet's classloader)
- `DriverManager.getConnection()` could fail because the URL is incorrect or the username/password is not valid
- `stmt.executeQuery(sql)` could be failing because your SQL syntax is incorrect or not valid for the database schema you are connected to.